# Will MSDN product keys still work after the subscription is expired?

Tags: licensing, bizspark

Will the product keys received through the BizSpark program still work after the MSDN subscription expires?

I'm currently using Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2013 which I got through BizSpark. I was wondering what happens when the subscription ends. Will all my installed products expire or can I still use the claimed keys after the subscription ends?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is **NOT** a concrete, answerable **programming** question ...

Comment: You should ask Microsoft and their licensing folks - this is off-topic here

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/faqs.aspx

Comment: My friend had BizSpark, and his Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Edition expired once his license expired. I think this is new to 2013 though, now that it requires more extensive logging in.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A quick answer before this gets closed...my recent experience with MSDN is that

- keys that do not require activation continue to work indefinitely
- products that have been activated continue to work indefinitely
- keys that require activation are historically quite variable in behaviour, but now mostly will no longer activate after your subscription has expired.
- you cannot claim new keys once your subscription expires.

MSDN is an amazing resource and very reasonably priced. Best thing is to regard it as a lifetime subscription. Having said that, we usually make sure we claim a few extra keys before we roll over each subscription. Some work, some don't.

Microsoft has been unhelpful in providing information about this, which I find quite understandable.